# colouring output of ls according to file extension

Tags: bash

I am working on some C++ files all of which are in a single folder.

When I do `ls` both the .cpp and the .h files show up in the same colour.

Is there a way to tell the bash shell that I want to display `.cpp` files in pink
and `.h` files in golden-brown?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're working with GNU coreutils (very likely if you're on Linux),  you're looking for the [`dir_colors`](http://tldp.org/LDP/LGNET/issue01to08/misc/dircolors.txt) utility.

If your distribution has already set everything up so that you get different colors in `ls` for some file types, you just need to, for example, copy `/etc/DIR_COLORS` to your `~/.dir_colors`, make the changes you want, then start a new shell to see the effects.

If not, still copy the file over to your home directory as above. Then you'll need to:

- put this somewhere in your shell's `rc` files:

  ```
  eval `dircolors ~/.dir_colors`
  ```
- alias `ls` to `ls --color=auto` (put that in your `rc` files as well)

You can get this on Mac OS X too via [coreutils](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=coreutils) MacPort. [A better ls for Mac OS X](http://hocuspokus.net/2008/01/a-better-ls-for-mac-os-x/) has some details on this (pay attention to the `with_default_names` option, make sure you understand the implications of using it if/before you do).

For FreeBSD (don't know if this applies to other BSD variants), the option for `ls` would be `-G`, and check out the [ls(1)](http://www.manpages.info/freebsd/ls.1.html) man page description for the *CLICOLORS* environment variable for a bit more info.

Comment: Only works with GNU `ls` unfortunately.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Mat that worked! Just a minor point for those interested in the post: It looks like the LS_COLORS variable defined by the `dircolors` package is the one that should be changed for this purpose. With `dircolors --print-database > ~/.dircolors` , we can modify the .dircolors file and place an `eval `dircolors ~/.dir_colors`` in our .bashrc, zshrc

Comment: Thanks for covering OS X and FreeBSD, my two other favorite platforms.